# Find max possible area of square and circle

Tags: analysis, functions, trigonometry, area

Given total perimeter is L. How to find max possible area of sum of both figures (square and circle) where x = perimeter of square and L - x is perimeter of circle.

How to build area function where represented both figures? From that function I could calculate derivative and find possible maximum point

Update:

x is between 0 < x < L

Comment: If you know the circle maximises area for a given perimeter (or that it does a better job than the square at least), the question is, is there any point in having the square at all?

Comment: I have updated my question. x is between 0 < x < L

Comment: Well why wouldn't you have $x\to0^+$?

Comment: By the length of the square and circle, do you mean perimeter?

Comment: why should me help  x→0+ ?
And yes Ross

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that by length you mean perimeter, a square of perimeter $x$ has a side of $\frac x4$ and therefore an area of $\frac {x^2}{16}$.  A circle of perimeter $L-x$ has a radius of ??? and an area of ???.  Add the areas together, take the derivative with respect to $x$, set to zero...  Don't forget to check the endpoints.

Comment: Thank you for hint. Am I on the right why? $f(x)=( \frac{x}{4})^{2} +(\frac{L-x}{2pi })^2$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = (\frac x4)^2 +\pi(\frac{L-x}{2\pi})^2$

$f' = 2\frac{x}{4}\frac{1}{4} + 2\pi(\frac{L-x}{2\pi})(\frac{-1}{2\pi}) = \frac x8+\frac{x-L}{2\pi} = (\pi+4)x-4L$

Set $f'=0$, solve for $x:$

$x = \frac {4L}{\pi+4}$

And, as Ross Millikan states below, this is not a max.  Checking the endpoints, the max is when $x=0$.  All circle, no square.

Comment: Side of a square of perimeter $x$ is $x/4$. Further, did you check if you have a maximum or minimum? Hint, you have a parabola which rises on both sides...

Comment: You have found a local minimum, not maximum.

Comment: Thought I'd fixed $f(x)$ yesterday.  And at $x=0, A = \frac{L^2}{4\pi}$, not $\frac{L}{4\pi}$...  So max is at $x=0$.  Sorry for my sloppiness!